# Is Using SQL Merge with only one table possible in python?

Tags: python, sql-server

Just wondering if it's possible to use the Merge statement in a python script when there is only a destination table?

For context - I am creating database entries of file names from a folder, however I only want to insert new records, and not update existing records.

Ordinarily, the merge statement needs the source table and destination table, I'm just wondering how I would go about substituting the source table with the list of file names created in python.

Is this possible, or is there a better way of going about it?

Comment: Use the `values` option to build a table of values as the `source`.

Comment: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/

Comment: @DaleK It does, it's given me something to work from for sure thanks!